# Terminator in MATLAB serial not working properly

Tags: matlab, serial-port, serial-communication

I have a proble regarding the Terminator in Matlab serial component.

```
% Open a port
port = serial (comPort, 'Baudrate', 38400, 'Flowcontrol', 'none' ...
 ,'Parity', 'none', 'StopBits', 1, 'DataBits', 8 ...
 ,'Terminator', {'CR/LF', 'CR'}...
 );
fopen (port);

initCmd = '/1ZR';

% initialize pump
fprintf(port, '%s\n', initCmd);
reply = fscanf(port)
```

The communication protocoll of my pump demands a carriage return for send and replies with a carriage return AND a line feed (and I hope I defined it right in the example code.

When I now send the initialization command, the pump initiates properly and sends the following `reply`:

```
>> reply =

ÿ/0@

>> int8(reply)

ans =

  127   47   48   64    3   13   10
```

But I get the following warning even though the reply contains `CR/LF`:

```
Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached.
```

The `reply` is correct except for the `127`. I do not expect this according to the manual. Is MATLAB interpreting the answer wrong completely?

Where is the problem? The last to numbers `13 10` represents the Terminator, but MATLAB is not able to detect it?

Comment: What happens you you specify *only* CR as a teminator?

Comment: The problem remains, I alreadt tried it... Using MATLAB 2013b by the way.

Comment: What if you pass 13 as terminator?

Comment: Still the same error.